# How do I find the fixed points of one isometry, from the fixed points of another isometry?

Tags: group-theory, isometry, fixed-points

I have an isometry group $G$ which acts on units of a ring  $R$ (not neessarily the full isometry group).  I know the set $P_f$ of fixed points in $R$ of one member $f$ of $G$.  Can I use the group rules of $G$ to find the corresponding fixed points $P_g$ in $R$ of another element $g$ of $G$ from the $P_f$ I have?  If so, how?

> Find $P_g=\{x\in R:gx=x\}$ from $P_f=\{x\in R:fx=x\}$

**My Attempt**

This is as much as I can work out: I've convinced myself that since $G$ is a group of homeomorphisms, then by [topological conjugacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy) every member of $G$ should have the same number of fixed points as the others.  Therefore the question has a solution.  Maybe that's wrong?

At first I thought this would be easy, just take the group member that takes one fixed point to another and I would be done. But I quickly realised it doesn't work like that.

So with a bit of head scratching I concluded I need to find the homeomorphism that topologically conjugates ones isometry to the other.  It's not immediate (to me at least) that this will be a member of $G$ although it should be a member of the full isometry group on $R$.  Am I barking up the right tree?

My next thought was that any subgroup of the isometry group has gotta generate a whole conjugacy group or something that's closed under conjugacy and that it's going to become complicated, but there is probably a method of taking $f$ and $g$ and generating that supergroup of conjugacies I'm talking about.

**Edit**

I'm coming round to the view that isometries are going to fall into conjugacy classes and that for me to expect them to have corresponding fixed points, they will need to be in the same conjugacy class.  Let's assume $f,g$ are in the same conjugacy class for the purposes of this question as I believe that to be the case in my specific example anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "by topological conjugacy"? Why all members of $G$ are conjugate? Is that an assumption?

Comment: @freakish it's a good question. For a moment you had me with the identity thing but then like you I realised the identity is completely fixed in $G$ but not in $R$. Anyway...back to your question and I ***think*** this is the answer to it. My thinking is that since $G$ is a set of homeomorphisms on $R$, each of its elements must topologically conjugate any homeomorphism on $R$ to some other homeomorphism on $R$. Now that may be a misconception I have jumped to because in my special case, all the isometries r very similar to each other. In which case i will have to ask a more specific question

Comment: actually @freakish as I think about this more, I'm coming to think the members of $G$ must fall into conjugacy classes.  And I think in the example I have in mind, I think my isometries are all in the same conjugacy class so I may add that to the question.

Comment: In this degree of generality you cannot do anything.

Comment: @MoisheKohan you can always do *something* but thank-you I accept your point that *something* here would be so vague as to be useless.  I'll reframe the specific instance.

Comment: You also need to know the conjugating element. Then the question has a simple answer, if not, it is again unanswerable.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Aha, now we're on to something. So I take that to mean that in some circumstances a first step is to find the conjugating element.  So I need to find the $h$ such that $hfh^{-1}=g$, correct? And since I have $f$ and $g$, maybe I can do that.  Am I right?

Comment: @MoisheKohan the special case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4781398/

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg wording adjusted. This question is now moot as I asked the particular case.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was probably answered in a comment here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4781262/how-do-i-find-the-fixed-points-of-one-isometry-from-the-fixed-points-of-another?noredirect=1#comment10162374_4781262 although confirmation would be helpful.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I added an answer based on what I learnt tonight.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is based upon the premise that the isometries are topologically conjugate to each other and therefore they must share the same numbers of fixed points, then the key is to find the conjugating map between them. That is the homeomorphism $h$ such that $hfh^{-1}=g$.

Incidentally, if the group is commutative (as it turned out my specific case is) the only conjugating element of the group is identity, so any suitable conjugating function would lie outside of the commutator.